# Android 4.0 launching app from url not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

im having a weird issue where instead of a url should launch my application, it is loading the application into the browser itself, in this case into mozella!

here is the intent filters i am using for my application if anyone can please tell me what im doing wrong.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:name=".Globals"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".RSS_ViewerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data android:scheme="itpc" />
               <data android:scheme="pcast" />
               <data android:scheme="feed" />
               <data android:scheme="feeds" />
               <data android:scheme="rss" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data android:mimeType="text/xml" android:scheme="http" />
               <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" android:scheme="http" />
               <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" android:scheme="http" />
               <data android:mimeType="text/xml" android:scheme="https" />
               <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" android:scheme="https" />
               <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="RSSFeedActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.CertificateAuthentication.Authenticator"></activity>
</application>
```

thanks.

**UPDATE**

Just a bit more information, when the dialog asking to chose and application to open the link in pops up, it doesnt ever display my app, or any for that matter.

**UPDATE**

I Removed the 2nd and 3rd intent filters, I attempted to merge the 2 remaining intent filters into 1, but that doesn't load the app from the browser. the code above is what it looks like now and gets me the same results as before =( which is annoying as it means users can have 2 sessions of the application running, one from the browser and one from the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third `<intent-filter>` elements may not work, as `android:host` is not documented to support a wildcard.

Comment: Cheers but that unfortunately didn't work =(

I've tried to change the action to main, but that doesnt work as the dialog asking to choose an application doesnt ever show my application!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is `\`. This is escape character, so to make this expression work you need `\\`.
[Documentation clearly says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path) that you need to use `\\.` for dot (there is example with `\\*`).

I also agree with CommonsWare answer, I've found in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) such statement:

> Each of these attributes is optional, but they are not independent of
>   each other: For an authority to be meaningful, a scheme must also be
>   specified. For a path to be meaningful, both a scheme and an authority
>   must be specified.

And `The host and port together constitute the URI authority` so in practice authority means host so you can't omit that and apparently you can't put a star there.

IMO you made it to complicated, you don't need define path here! Mime type should do the job. Try to find some open source projects which reads RSS and see how they defined manifest.

I think you needed something like that:

```
<activity
    android:name=".RSS_ViewerActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="itpc" />
        <data android:scheme="pcast" />
        <data android:scheme="feed" />
        <data android:scheme="feeds" />
        <data android:scheme="rss" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/xml" android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/xml" android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml" android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i took out those 2 intent filters as you and commonsware suggested, i have updated my post above.
i still get the same results though =( i also tried it from another browser, the stock android one, and i get the same results of the application is viewed from the browser rather then launching/resuming if it is running.